# SQL Query inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on SQL Server 2008 R2. 
I have two tables let us say `TblGroup` and `TblComplatedDetails`.

TblGroup contains the name of Groups along with `MemberId` and `GroupType (i.e. in Daily, Weekly, Start, End)` and `TblComplatedDetails` contains `GroupId (i.e. foreign key of TblGroup)` along with completed datetime. 
Now I want all the group of specific `MemberId` except `GroupType="End"` AND "Start" type of Group only if it has no record in TblCompletedDetails. So the record set is something like below :

```
TblGroup 
==================================
Id  MemberId    GroupType
==================================
1   1       Daily
2   2       Daily
3   3       Daily
4   1       Weekly
5   1       Start
6   2       Weekly 
7   2       Start 
8   2       End
9   1       End
10  1       End


TblCompletedDetails
======================================
Id  GroupId     CompletedDate
======================================
1   1       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2   2       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3   3       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
4   4       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
5   1       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
6   2       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
7   3       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
8   5       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
9   6       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So for MemberId = 1 the desired Groups can be :

```
=======
GroupId
=======
1
4
```

But for MemberId = 2 the desired resule is :

```
=======
GroupId 
=======
2
6
7
```

Because 7 is a "Start" type of Group that has not foreign key in TblCompletedDetails.
Can anyone have idea? Awaiting for your valuable response.

Comment: condition you might need to use **TblGroup grp**
1. **grp.GroupType not in ('End')**
2. **grp.GroupType = 'Start' and (select count(*) from TblCompletedDetails tcd where grp.GroupId = tcd.GroupId)**

Comment: @NaveenBabu In that case I will only get the records that are of "start" type of group only. I want all the type of groups except with type "End" and for "start" type of group there must not be the record in TblCompledDetails.

Answer (score 2):

```
select g.ID GroupID
  from TblGroup g
 where g.MemberID = @MemberID
   and g.GroupType <> 'end'
   and
   (
       -- Row is qualified if it is not start
          g.GroupType <> 'start'
       -- Or, if it is, does not have an entry in TblCompletedDetails
       or not exists (select *
                        from TblCompletedDetails d
                       where d.GroupId = g.ID)
   )
```